# Notice: Undefined index: txt_image in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbconnectioncheck.php on line 11

Tags: php

Why its giving error?any idea

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $obj_image->image_name=str_replace("'","''",$_POST['txt_image_name']);
     $obj_image->image=str_replace("'","''",$_POST['txt_image']);//line 11
     $obj_image->insert_into_image();
}
```

Comment: Chk do u have $_POST['txt_image'] text_image in form

Comment: yes i have $_POST('txt_image')in form

Comment: $obj_image->image=str_replace("','",$_POST['txt_image']);